# How do I perform a DNS zone transfer (AXFR) using Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, dns

I'm trying to do a DNS zone transfer and would like to do it using Ruby 1.9. Are there any gems built-in or otherwise that will do this simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I tried dnsruby, I found [net-dns](http://net-dns.rubyforge.org/) to be more intutive.

net-dns is a close port of the Net::DNS from perl, and shares almost all the same methods.

dnsruby ended up being extremely verbose just to do a simple zone transfer.

Installing net-dns was as simple as "gem install net-dns". After creating a new Net::DNS::Resolver object, I used #axfr to perform the zone transfer which worked nicely.

In cases where zone transfer wasn't enabled, I simply used #query or #search.

Comment: four lines is "extremely verbose"?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Dnsruby](http://dnsruby.rubyforge.org/).

If it doesn't do what you need, the author is still maintaining it.